# How to use RestTemplate to get result in List and put the response into List?

Tags: java, spring, microservices, resttemplate

Hi what i trying to achieve is i want to consume other API and put some response data into List in my function using RestTemplate, here is how my code look like :

```
@PostMapping("/save-new")
public ResponseEntity<ShipmentAddressGrouping> saveNewShipmentAddressGrouping(@Valid @RequestBody InputRequest<ShipmentAddressGroupingDto> request) {
    String url = baseUrl + "/load-list";

    HttpEntity<PartnerShipmentDto> requestPartnerShipmentDto = new HttpEntity<>(new PartnerShipmentDto());
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    List<PartnerShipmentDto> partnerShipmentDto = restTemplate.postForObject(url, requestPartnerShipmentDto, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<PartnerShipmentDto>>() {});

    ShipmentAddressGrouping newShipmentAddressGrouping = shipmentAddressGroupingService.save(request);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(newShipmentAddressGrouping);

}
```

as you can see i try to get the response in to List, which is i try here `restTemplate.postForObject(url, requestPartnerShipmentDto, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<PartnerShipmentDto>>() {});`

but i got error underlined in restTemplate.postForObject that look like this :

> The method postForObject(String, Object, Class, Object...) in the
> type RestTemplate is not applicable for the arguments (String,
> HttpEntity, new
> ParameterizedTypeReference<List>(){})

What should i change to fix this?

Comment: Haven't tried `postForObject` myself, but from looking at: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html it looks like the trinary for of `postForObject` requires the 3'rd argument to be the responseType, so `List.class` would work in your case, though you would get a warning about generics.

Comment: hi @BillNaylor that worked for me too but yeah i got warning about generics and i choose to use Bernard answer to use exchange rather than postForObject then, so i can specify another method too, thank you. i will find where List.class can be use in future thank u very much

Comment: I think to avoid the generics warning, you can encapsulate the `List<PartnerShipmentDto>` in your own class, then reference that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `ParameterizedTypeReference<T>`, you need to use `RestTemplate.exchange()`, since this is the only Method that exposes a parameter of type `ParameterizedTypeReference<T>`.

```
List<PartnerShipmentDto> partnerShipmentDto = restTemplate.exchange(url, 
                HttpMethod.GET, 
                requestPartnerShipmentDto,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<PartnerShipmentDto>>() {})
        .getBody();
```

Comment: I dont think you need to use exchange function..  postForObject also will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above but it did not work for me.
This works nicely in Kotlin:

```
  val uri = "http://localhost:$port/api/xxx/dosomething/"
  log.info("URL for Controller was: [$uri]") 
  val result: ResponseEntity<Array<BillingOrder>>
                = restTemplate!!.postForEntity(uri, ids, Array<BillingOrder>::class.java)
  assertNotNull(result)
  assertEquals(200, result.statusCodeValue)
  val body = result.body
  if (body != null) {
     body.forEach { order ->
       assertEquals("Success", order.billingState)
  } else {
    fail("Response body is null!")
  }
```

On a tangent, if you have a post that does NOT return a value but takes params, here is that one:

```
  uri = "http://localhost:$port/api/xxx/doSomething/${subscription.id}/"
  log.info("URL for Controller was: [$uri]")
  val x = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, null, Void::class.java)
  assertNotNull(x)
  assertEquals(HttpStatus.SC_OK, x.statusCodeValue)
```